# Speed up add users to groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

Currently we have a script which will add for example 100 users into 100 separate groups. This makes 10.000 'lines' of code to be processed.

For each line we do:

```
Try {
  add-adgroupmember -identity "CN=...." -Members "CN=..."
} catch {
  Add-content ...
}
```

If the script is rather small then it isn't a problem. But if you have to grant 100.000 group memberships, this will take a lot of time. I have already used the method of adding an user array to a group. This goes a lot faster, but when 1 user gives an error or maybe a couple of them, you only receive 1 error message. And to be sure to know which one, you need to loop through these users to check which isn't in the group.

Is there a way to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

Using the .net classes for AD directly instead of the AD cmdlets is supposed to be much faster, especially the ones found under the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace are supposed to work pretty fast.

As an alternative you can try to run the "adds" parallel (through a workflow or with jobs).

Answer (score 0):

The most likely errors in this scenario are:

1. User not existing or disabled/renamed
2. User is already a member of one of the groups

These are easy to work around:

```
# List of Users
$Users  = "John01","Joe02","Kyle45"
# List of groups we want to make them members of
$Groups = "Finance Users","Accountants"

# Remove all users that don't exist or are disabled
$Users = $Users |Where-Object { try {
        Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq $true -and SAMAccountName -eq $_" -ErrorAction Stop
        $true
    } catch { $false } }


foreach($Group in $Groups){
    # Check if any of the users are already members of the group
    $CurrentGroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SAMAccountName
    $NewMembers = $Users |Where-Object { $CurrentGroupMembers -notcontains $_ }

    # Add the remaining users to the group all at once
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $NewMembers
}
```

Now we've reduced 10.000 LDAP requests to 300 at most (yay)